# Events FOSUserBundle Symfony2 on register and login

Tags: php, events, symfony, fosuserbundle

I'm trying to implement events on FOSUserBundle

```
<?php
namespace EasyApp\UserBundle\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Registry as Doctrine; 
use EasyApp\UserBundle\Entity\UserLogin;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserBundle;


class LoginManager implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    /** @var \Symfony\Component\Security\Core\SecurityContext */
    private $securityContext;

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager */
    private $em;

    /**
     * Constructor
     *
     * @param SecurityContext $securityContext
     * @param Doctrine        $doctrine
     */
    public function __construct(SecurityContext $securityContext, Doctrine $doctrine)
    {
        $this->securityContext = $securityContext;
        $this->em = $doctrine->getEntityManager();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
                FOSUserEvents::SECURITY_IMPLICIT_LOGIN => 'onSecurityImplicitLogin',
                FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED=> 'onRegistrationCompleted'
        );
    }

    public function onSecurityImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)
    {
        die;
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $request = $event->getRequest();

        if ($this->securityContext->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY')) {
            // user has just logged in
            $this->saveLogin($request, $user);
        }
    }

    public function onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event){
        $user = $event->getAuthenticationToken()->getUser();
        $request = $event->getRequest();
        saveLogin($request, $user);
    }

    public function saveLogin($request, $user){
        $login = new UserLogin();
        $login->setIp($request->getClientIp());
        $login->setUser($user);

        $this->em->persist($login);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

And my service

```
services:
    user_login_manager:
        class: 'EasyApp\UserBundle\Service\LoginManager'
        arguments: ['@security.context', '@doctrine']
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'fos_user.security.interactive_login'}
            - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber', event: 'fos_user.registration.completed'}
```

But I have problems. When I login nothing happen, the `getSubscribedEvents()` is called but not `onSecurityImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)`

And the other problem is on register. Following error occurs on `onSecurityImplicitLogin(UserEvent $event)`

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to EasyApp\UserBundle\Service\LoginManager::onSecurityImplicitLogin() must be an instance of EasyApp\UserBundle\Service\UserEvent, instance of FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent given in /Users/antoine/Documents/projects/easyApp/application/src/EasyApp/UserBundle/Service/LoginManager.php line 46
```

and if I comment this line I got the same error on  `onRegistrationCompleted(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)`

Edit

```
services:
    user_login_manager:
        class: 'EasyApp\UserBundle\Service\LoginManager'
        arguments: ['@security.context', '@doctrine']
        tags:
            - { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber'}
            - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two points:

1. In the service definition `- { name: 'kernel.event_subscriber'}` is enough, no event entry. This the difference between subscriber and listener. A listener can only listen to one event, defined trough `event` and `method` params in the service definition. A subscriber can listen to multiple events, defined trough the method `getSubscribedEvents()`, so no further params in the service definition needed.
2. Second point, you are type hinting against the event classes (`UserEvent` and`FilterUserResponseEvent`), but you never imported them, so PHP assumes them in the same namespace (as said in the error message).

   ```
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\UserEvent;
   use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FilterUserResponseEvent;
   ```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I add - { name: 'kernel.event_listener', event: 'security.interactive_login' } in my service to detect normal login

Comment: Does mixing `kernel.event_listener` and `kernel.event_subscriber` tags work?