# How to install FOSUserBundle dev-master without updating the dependency SonataUserBundle?

Tags: symfony, dependencies, composer-php, fosuserbundle, sonata-user-bundle

I'm using `sonata-project/user-bundle:^2.2` and its dependency `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle:~1.3`. Now I want to install `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle:dev-master`. I tried

```
composer require friendsofsymfony/user-bundle:dev-master
```

I got the following error:

```
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
- sonata-project/user-bundle 2.2.4 requires friendsofsymfony/user-bundle ~1.3 -> satisfiable by
friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
- Can only install one of: friendsofsymfony/user-bundle[dev-master, 1.3.x-dev].
- Installation request for friendsofsymfony/user-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by friendsofsy
mfony/user-bundle[dev-master].
- Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle == 2.2.4.0 -> satisfiable by sonata-projec
t/user-bundle[2.2.4].
```

The latest stable release of `sonata-project/user-bundle` is `2.2.4` and its maximum requirement of `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` is `~1.3`. I want to install `friendsofsymfony/user-bundle` `dev-master/2.0.x-dev` to get some latest updates.

How can I install it without `sonata-project/user-bundle`updated?

Comment: Not possible. Maybe sonata master is compatible

Comment: I want to implement some event subscribers such as http://stackoverflow.com/q/17566446/1179841 (where you answered). It's only available in FOSUserBundler `dev-master`. How can I do that? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. Even the dev-master of the sonata user bundle requires FOS user bundle at ~1.3 and thus not combatible to the latest master of the FOS user bundle

Comment: Well, I solved this using custom login event listener without using FOSUser event subscribers. So it doesn't need to install FOSUser `dev-master`

Answer (score 0):

I think aliasing would do this but it's not recommended as the dependencies are generally there for a reason.

```
"require": {
    "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle": "dev-master as 1.3.6"
}
```

Comment: This will break the whole application

Comment: That may be true but that wasn't the question. The question was how to how to install it, not how to install it and successfully use it within the application. As I said in my response `it's not recommended as the dependencies are generally there for a reason`.